# How to show html code in webpage(front) ? I have tired<pre>but is not working in wordpress + Elementor

Tags: wordpress, tags, elementor

Could you please let me know how you can make code visible in front with proper intent using
pre and code tags

See image: **https://prnt.sc/KtrB2Dki8sBz**

I have tried but have not gotten it right. then tried with  but why  is not working in WordPress : **https://prnt.sc/gFSxAsCcAus0**

-> **https://prnt.sc/CLVzA55PUzH1**